# Do any other results depend on $S_5$ being the first unsolvable symmetric group?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I distinctly remember reading an answer, either here or on mathoverflow, which described some phenomenon in which a mathematical pattern held for 1, 2, 3, 4, and broke down at 5, and added that the reason five was the magic number was "essentially the same reason" that polynomials are solvable for degrees up to four but no further. I presume this meant it was because $S_5$ is the first unsolvable symmetric group.

Does anybody remember what question this was? Failing that, does anyone know of a theorem fitting this description?

Comment: http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=152, search "width-5" in the comments to get a citation.